# Oracle NET - How to enable SOURCE_ROUTE with LOAD_BALANCE and FAILOVER?

Tags: oracle

Lets say we have the following tns local naming:

```
CMAN =
    (DESCRIPTION=
    (SOURCE_ROUTE=YES)
    (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.0.16)(PORT=1522)) ###CMAN
    (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=sat-scan)(PORT=1521))
        (CONNECT_DATA=
           (SERVICE_NAME=satdb)
           (FAILOVER_MODE=
           (TYPE=SELECT)
           (METHOD=BASIC)
           (RETRIES=10)
           (DELAY=1)
           )
           )
    )
```

**SOURCE_ROUTE=YES is:**

> When you set this parameter to on or yes, Oracle Net uses each address
> in order until the destination is reached. To use Oracle Connection
> Manager, an initial connection from the client to Oracle Connection
> Manager is required,  and a second connection from Oracle Connection
> Manager to the listener is required.

But if we have two cman's?
how to implement LOAD_BALANCE and FAILOVER parameters? is this correct?

```
    CMAN =
        (DESCRIPTION=
        (LOAD_BALANCE=ON)
        (FAILOVER=ON)
        (SOURCE_ROUTE=YES)
        (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.0.16)(PORT=1522))  ###CMAN
        (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.0.17)(PORT=1522))  ###CMAN
        (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=sat-scan)(PORT=1521))
            (CONNECT_DATA=
               (SERVICE_NAME=satdb)
               (FAILOVER_MODE=
               (TYPE=SELECT)
               (METHOD=BASIC)
               (RETRIES=10)
               (DELAY=1)
               )
               )
        )
```

I mean, it must balance and failover only arround `192.168.0.16:1522` and `192.168.0.17:1522`, but I guess it would consider `sat-scan:1521` as well and maybe the client connect directly thought `scan-scan` without pass by cman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load balance multiple DESCRIPTIONs, with each DESCRIPTION providing different SOURCE_ROUTEs, like this:

```
CMAN =
    (DESCRIPTION_LIST=
        (LOAD_BALANCE=YES)
        (FAILOVER=ON)
        (DESCRIPTION=
            (SOURCE_ROUTE=YES)
            (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.0.16)(PORT=1522))
            (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=sat-scan)(PORT=1521))
            (CONNECT_DATA=
                (SERVICE_NAME=satdb)
                (FAILOVER_MODE=
                (TYPE=SELECT)
                (METHOD=BASIC)
                (RETRIES=10)
                (DELAY=1)
            )
        )
        (DESCRIPTION=
            (SOURCE_ROUTE=YES)
            (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.0.17)(PORT=1522))
            (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=sat-scan)(PORT=1521))
            (CONNECT_DATA=
                (SERVICE_NAME=satdb)
                (FAILOVER_MODE=
                (TYPE=SELECT)
                (METHOD=BASIC)
                (RETRIES=10)
                (DELAY=1)
            )
        )
    )
```

The following should also work, and be a little more compact. In this case, the route goes first to a *list* of addresses for the connection managers, which are set for load balancing and failover, then is directed on to the RAC SCAN address regardless of which connection manager is used:

```
CMAN =
    (DESCRIPTION=
        (SOURCE_ROUTE=YES)
        (ADDRESS_LIST=
            (LOAD_BALANCE=YES)
            (FAILOVER=ON)
            (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.0.16)(PORT=1522))
            (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.0.17)(PORT=1522))
        )
        (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=sat-scan)(PORT=1521))
        (CONNECT_DATA=
            (SERVICE_NAME=satdb)
            (FAILOVER_MODE=
            (TYPE=SELECT)
            (METHOD=BASIC)
            (RETRIES=10)
            (DELAY=1)
        )
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, working fine. Is this case (FAILOVER=ON) isn't necessary after DESCRIPTION_LIST?

Comment: Good catch: it is needed. I'll update. Thanks!